# Mysql Fetching rows base on date

Tags: mysql

Here's the code:

```
SELECT  RD.INTREQDQUANTITY, I.strItemName, v.strVendName, iu.strItemUnitName,  
          ip.dblItemPAmount, MAX(ip.dtmItemPasOf) AS EXR 
FROM TBLREQUESTDETAILS RD,tblitem I,tblvendor v,tblitemunit iu,tblitemprice ip` 
WHERE RD.strReqDItemCode = I.strItemCode 
AND RD.strReqDItemUnitCode = iu.strItemUnitCode 
AND RD.strReqDVendCode = v.strVendCode 
AND i.strItemCode = ip.strItemPItemCode 
and RD.strReqDReqHCode = 'RQST121' 
GROUP BY RD.INTREQDQUANTITY,I.strItemName,v.strVendName,iu.strItemUnitName, ip.dblItemPAmount
ORDER BY EXR desc ;
```

AND Here's The result:
[image]

What should I do If I want to fetch the current price for each itemname,vendorname and itemunit?? I want to fetch only those rows who's price is the Latest... Help me please those with boxes are the rows that i want to fetch

Comment: I think you must remove RD.INTREQDQUANTITY from group by if you want the result for this combination (itemname,vendorname and itemunit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use where in the grouped value (and use explicict join notatio)

```
SELECT  RD.INTREQDQUANTITY, I.strItemName, v.strVendName, iu.strItemUnitName,  
          ip.dblItemPAmount, ip.dtmItemPasOf AS EXR 
FROM TBLREQUESTDETAILS RD
INNER JOIN tblitem I ON RD.strReqDItemCode = I.strItemCode 
INNER JOIN tblvendor v ON D.strReqDVendCode = v.strVendCode 
INNER JOIN tblitemunit iu ON RD.strReqDItemUnitCode = iu.strItemUnitCode 
INNER JOIN tblitemprice ip ON i.strItemCode = ip.strItemPItemCode 
WHERE RD.strReqDReqHCode = 'RQST121' 
and ( RD.INTREQDQUANTITY, I.strItemName, v.strVendName, iu.strItemUnitName, ip.dtmItemPasOf) 

    in ( SELECT  RD.INTREQDQUANTITY, I.strItemName, v.strVendName, iu.strItemUnitName,  
          MAX(ip.dtmItemPasOf) 
        FROM TBLREQUESTDETAILS RD
        INNER JOIN tblitem I ON RD.strReqDItemCode = I.strItemCode 
        INNER JOIN tblvendor v ON D.strReqDVendCode = v.strVendCode 
        INNER JOIN tblitemunit iu ON RD.strReqDItemUnitCode = iu.strItemUnitCode 
        INNER JOIN tblitemprice ip ON i.strItemCode = ip.strItemPItemCode 
        WHERE RD.strReqDReqHCode = 'RQST121'  
        GROUP BY RD.INTREQDQUANTITY,I.strItemName,v.strVendName,iu.strItemUnitName 
    )
 ORDER BY EXR desc ;
```

(and use explicict join notation .. i think is more readable)

Comment: 0 rows returned :(

Comment: I mean only returns the row with the highest dtmPAsOf

Comment: Looking to you sample seems  which is the column you want .. ?

Comment: I want to fetch those that are inside  the black box, green box and red box.Which are row which contains the latest price base on date

Comment: I'm sorry but  The highest dtmPAsOf  is not the latest date ... and the the related rows  should contain the last price (alias dblItemPAmount) based on date ... ? ..

Comment: I mean, for example for the item - yum burger , vendor jollibee - item unit piece. There are 4 rows... I want to fetch the row with the greatest dtmPAsOf.. I want to fetch the latest row for yum burger , vendor jollibee - item unit piece. I want also to fetch the same with fudgee barr and mapex drum set. Help me please I really need to finish this one sir Pleasee I'm beggin you

Comment: I'm sorry but from my select  which row  is selected  (if is not the black row ) .. is the 2, the 4 ) ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125785/discussion-between-poorgrammer-and-scaisedge).